# c# Getting file from project

Tags: c#, path, archive

I have a solution that contains a lot of projects, I just put an archive in the next path Solution -> Project('Functions') -> Folder('Pantallas') -> File('markercluster.js')

and now I want to reference this archive, getting the path of the current location of the application plus 'Functions/Pantallas/markercluster.js'

how I can do that?

Comment: I think you want to read embedded Resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get the executablePath and then eliminated the .exe

```
string exePath = Application.ExecutablePath;
```

and then IN MY CASE( cause my .exe name is 21 characters length)

```
 exePath = exePath.Substring(0,exePath.Length-21);
```